# Running kaa notification demo

Tags: error-handling, notifications, kaa

When i run the notification demo,following warning and errors are shown [click here for image description](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uv5F4.jpg)

Please let me know how to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like a connection problem. Meaning your SDK is not able to reach kaa sandbox server. Make sure your server is running properly.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply